# backgroundImage style not loaded - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use `backgroundImage` style but not rendered:

```
style={{backgroundImage: `url(${slider.img})`}
```

`slider` is a object.

this is my whole `div` tag:

```
div className="row owl-item"  id="bestOffer" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${slider.img})`}}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put URL string in quotes for CSS:

```
<div 
    className="row owl-item" 
    id="bestOffer" 
    style={{
        backgroundImage: `url("${slider.img}")`
    }}
>
```